# Using C# tuples in EF Core model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have class with list of bounded length (length = 6), and I want to store it inside a class with no other relationships, something like this:

```
public class LobbyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Tuple<int?, int?, int?, int?, int?, int?> Team1 { get; set; }
    public Tuple<int?, int?, int?, int?, int?, int?> Team2 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to do this other than bluntly inserting int's into a class?

Comment: Regardless of the DB model, using tuples for this is ugly. It would be just about OK for a list of *exactly* 6 items, but if it's merely *at most* 6 items a tuple is pretty clearly the wrong thing to use -- what's the semantics of `(1, 2, 3, null, null, 4)`, and is it the same as `(null, null, 4, 2, 1, 3)`? The relevant bit would be that there's a list (or set, even), not that it happens to have at most 6 items. Verifying that there's no more than 6 items and mapping it to the DB should be separate concerns.

Comment: Why don't you want any external relationship here? I am guessing the ints being pulled are PK so if your just going to grab the players later then put it into an object. This almost seems like an attempt to avoid boxing by placing the data into a struct.